# If two knots are tricolourable does this imply that they are 3 equivalent?

Tags: general-topology, knot-theory, knot-invariants

In reading the knot book there was a question regarding that 3 moves preserve tricolouration and pointing to if a knot is tricolourable and 3 equivalent to another knot then the other knot is also tricolourable. Is the reverse true as well? A knot is tricolourable therefore it is 3 equivalent to every other tricolourable knot? I think this would be easily disproved by finding a contradiction.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello and welcome to MSE!  When you say 3 equivalent, what do you mean?  Defining this might help.  And thinking about the definition of each together might let you answer your own question.

Comment: @N.Owad 3-equivalence is when you add the tangle replacement move that 3-twists can be replaced with 0-twists. I vaguely remember looking into this before and found that either this was an open question or that it was false (but I can neither remember nor find what paper I'd looked at!)